# Option to close bounty enabled questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

Recently, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64279640/12578202) and the post is missing with the debugging details. So it should be closed with ***"Needs debugging details"*** option.

I could have voted to close this post and move on, but, since it is on a bounty, maybe I should use some event reminders. But, I wish there should be ***some queue***, which processes the action after the bounty period.

That is, people can vote to close the question and after the bounty period if the total votes reach the level (three votes, right? ) the post should automatically get closed.

- Does this requirement/feature make any sense? (to me, yes)
- What should I do in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

Comment: That is very accurate @Larnu